# Noise at 2^n transitions

Tags: adc, noise, image-sensor

I am sampling a video signal from a linear imager. I noticed when the illumination is just at the intensity when the ADC increases by another MSB bit at the output, the noise occurs. That is, when ADC transitions from 0111 to 1000, 01111 to 10000 and so on. It happens at every transition. At least, this is how it appears to me. What could be the source of such noise?

[image]

I suspect, this happens somewhere on the digital side of the circuit. Here's the quantitative profile of the image intensity at the line20:

[image]

Here's the sample clock signal before and after the gate buffer:

yellow: 0-3.3V

blue:0-5V

[image]

**EDIT:**
In short: the problem was with timing that is discussed in this post and the bad grounding that is discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122548/is-it-safe-to-use-a-bus-buffer-as-level-shifter)

Comment: I would assume it to be just an effect from the switching off of those outputs on the adc.  The noise goes away thereafter the ADC has switched to 1000, right?

Comment: @ShannonStrutz Well, as I increase the illumination, the brightness on the image increases. But at some point, the noise appears. As I keep increasing the illumination, the noise goes away and the image gets brighter. After increasing the illumination even more, the noise appears again. Then disappears. And so on until ADC saturation.

Comment: On the image above, I could not produce a good intensity gradient to demonstrate the noise with periodic occurrence relative to illumination intensity.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Then my first instinct would be that is coming from the internal switching of the ADC

Comment: Look at the power supply rails with a 'scope... (AC coupled maybe)  Then try some more bypass capacitance.  I'll sometimes add a bit of resistance (1-10 ohms) in the supply line to the "noisy" chip with a bypass cap after the R.  (Maybe bypass caps on both sides.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold just updated the question, please see more detailed schematic with PCB layout.

Comment: Precisely what is the greenish picture representing in terms of noise levels and how much is 1 bit in terms of voltage?

Comment: @Andyaka Input voltage to ADC (differential) range: 2VACp-p + 1.5VDC. 12bit ADC, so little less that 5mV per LSB. So, the image intensity profile of the line20 ranges from 0-255 levels. See the updated post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placeholder's valid comments notwithstanding, the noise you are seeing is indicative of a timing skew problem among the digital bits coming out of the ADC. Instead of xxx10000 and xxx01111, you are occasionally getting xxx00000 and xxx11111.

I see the clock going into the ADC, but I don't see the next place in the datapath where the data is clocked again. Be sure that the timing delays (resistors, buffer, connectors, wiring, etc.) on the data lines still meet the setup and hold requirements for wherever that reclocking occurs. Pay attention to clock skew among the boards, too.

Comment: I sample the signal from via NI PCI6259. The sampling trigger is the same clock as for the ADC. I assume the signal from CPLD is identical, then it follows identical SGLs, one for each. I expect that the PCI board lags the trigger clock because of: 1) small delay in the buffer and 2) the setup delay in the PCI internal circuitry. But then, I could have random noise not correlated with 2^n transitions. Right?

Comment: I skimmed through the [manual for the PCI6259](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371291h.pdf), but couldn't easily see its setup/hold requirements for the digital inputs. Can you try sampling the data on the opposite edge of the clock?

Comment: Strangely, do not see the difference.

Comment: I just halfed sampling frequency and noise disappeared. Any clues?

Comment: It means we're on the right track. What sampling frequency are you using? You never said.

Comment: 10MHz, which is the limiting sampling frequency of the PCI. At 5MHz the image is smooth and clean, except some lower frequency ripple across the entire image, barely visible.

Comment: I just added the intensity profile of the line #20 on the image above. The left and right spikes are around 64 and the central is even more messed up. But I would claim it is at the intensity 128 (out of 255.).

Comment: Another observation. I think I have 4 or 5 intensities around which significant noise occurs. There are might be more such transition intensities, but they are not as obvious. I was dumb to design only one ground wire going with the digital signal to the PCI card. Adding extra digital wire helps to reduce some of that noise, but not effective enough to eliminate it. But why? It's a 5V digital signal - too big range for errors. Maybe pulling down all digital lines will help?

Comment: We've pretty solidly established that your problem is with *timing*, not voltage levels or electrical noise. You need to focus on the analysis of your datapath with repsect to the clock(s) that drive it, taking into account all sources of skew, delay and setup/hold times.

Comment: This is perhaps a nice conceptual case for [Gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), although the fundamental timing problem is more important to solve.

Comment: Dave, I checked all the data-paths with respect to the clocks. All seems to be intact. Do you really think I have timing problems? If that was true, would not the problem exist for the entire range of values, and not only at the 2^n transitions? Also, take a look at the clock signal before and after the SLG buffer (posted). The digital signal line signals look even worse. Is it just my oscilloscope or why do the buffers screw up the signal so badly?

Comment: Last thing first: The waveforms look like you either don't have your probes compensated properly, or you have an excessively long ground lead. The faster edges at the output of the SLG produce greater overshoot. With regard to the datapath timing: Were you able to establish exactly what the setup and hold time requirements are for the NI board? It's clear from your image that it's just "barely on the edge" of working, so the fact that it's data-dependent is not at all surprising.

Comment: It works at 5 MHz but not at 10 MHz. What about intermediate frequencies? Use a function generator as an external clock source.

Comment: Timing must be all good. I tried to delay sampling clock by up to 20ns, sampling on falling/rizing edge - no difference if not worse. I think the problem is somewhere in the [SN74ABT5402A](http://www.bdtic.com/DataSheet/TI/SN74ABT5402A.pdf). I believe it messes everything up. I supply it with 5V, but the inputs are 3.3V. Given that my scope readings are not very good, I can not know for sure the integrity of the buffer's output. I suspect it does not provide proper 0/5V TTL. I thought that it can level shift from 3.3V to 5V, however, the datasheet does not explicitly say so. Bad choice?

Comment: In addition to timing problem, there was also a grounding problem that is discussed [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122548/is-it-safe-to-use-a-bus-buffer-as-level-shifter)

Answer (score 2):

I'll start off by saying that you appear to be taking care of a few things correctly.  Controlling edge rates(resistors), adding a buffer/driver (745402) etc.

Well you can probably rule out the ADC internal workings, Analog is an excellent company, they know what they are doing and they've sold lots of those devices, and I've used these devices in this exact application with good results.

Now for the constructive criticism.

The ADC is a very sensitive device (wide BW and high level of conversion) you have to be careful.

Power supplies:

- for these applications I typically run dedicated LDO's, filters before (Pi filters with L's and C's) and after for the buffers and the ADC's - all separate.

Clock driver for ADC:

- rail bounce on the clock source manifests itself in jitter on the sampling aperture which manifests itself in MSB counting noise.  - separate power supply and driver form the clock.  The SGL (Single gate Logic) is your friend.

Layout - Layout and yet again layout:

- Is very important.  BE aware of image current flow, the return paths of the signals that are running to the buffers.  Ground plane splits etc. etc.

Some more obscure things:
- some resistor packs are nasty, additional inductance and cross -coupling capacitance.  It wouldn't necessarily affect your results here.  I tend to use individual resistors (0402)

As per DaveTweed excellent observation (re timing skew) one solution is to replace the buffers in your schematic with D ff's /latches to reclock the data **and** buffer it at the same time.  I normally do that and Dave's comment reminded me.

After update (comments about clocking);

I never, ever , ever allow FPGA, CPLD inputs into an ADC.  I either run a separate clock source or if I have to have a specific clock frequency that is generated, I reclock using SGL's (D FF's) at a higher frequency (paying attention to setup and hold times of course). The reason for this is that the structure of FPGA's and CPL's causes a lot of power rail sourced jitter in the timing of the outputs from these devices.  This jitter in turn interacts with the sampling window of the aperature period of the ADC front end causing noise problems.

Comment: Please, see the update. My ADC has a separate LDO power supply (ADC_Vcc). The clock comes from a CPLD through an SGL, where CPLD and SGL share the same power supply. I do use PI filters with ferite beads. Regarding the layout, that's my first experience, but I have a second ground plane, with no splits, though. Could you please, see if that would be a problem?

Comment: @Naz I updated the post. However, that probably would NOT have the pattern that you are seeing (i.e. SSO - Simultaneously Switching Outputs) on majority movement.  However, I will note that having your SGL on the same rails at the CPLD is a big issue.  Are you feeding the data back into teh same CPLD?

Comment: the data is fed to NI PCI6259 for sampling. However, eventually it will be fed back to the CPLD or FPGA. Why is it a big issue?