# Is it safe to use a bus buffer as level shifter?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, buffer, logic-level, level-translation

I am currently using [SN74ABT5402ADW](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/scbs660b-112955.pdf) as a buffer and level shifter for my ADC, however, the datasheet does not explicitly say that it can be used as a level shifter. I provide it with 5V power, but the input signals (out of the ADC) are 3.3V. The performance is bad: when I scope the signal on the output pins, the signal is not even close to look like binary HI/LOW. It does have rise/fall edges, but HI/LOW values seem to float, especially at xxx1111 to xx10000 transitions. **I suspect** that it does not convert the signal from 3.3V to 5V **properly**. Could anyone tell me if I am misusing it as described, and what can I do to make it work?

I use [BNC2110](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/372121f.pdf) and [CB-68LP](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/373853a.pdf) connector blocks that connect to three PF50 connectors shown on the schematic. The bloks, in turn, are connected to [NI PCI6259](http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~elkvsza/jegyzetek/DAQmx_angol.pdf).

[image]

Measured signal at the input (yellow) and the output (blue) of '5402A when **it is not** connected to the NI connector blocks.

[image]

Measured signal at the input (yellow) and the output (blue) of '5402Awhen **it is** connected to the NI connector blocks via 8" unshielded wires.

[image]

Power at the power pin of the '5402A:

[image]

**All ground pins on both NI connector blocks are interconnected internally.**

- Cable 1-3: Digital lines
- Cable 4: trigger signal and GND wire
- Cable 5: GND wire

[image]

Comment: Is the input voltage to the '5402 at least 2 V? In what way is the performance "bad"? What kind of load are you driving and have you considered the effect of the '5402's 25-ohm output resistance?

Comment: @ThePhoton See post update, please. I can not find from the datasheet what kind of load I am driving. And I did not consider the effect of the 25ohm output resistance. What does it do?

Comment: When you put the scope probe on the input pins of the '5402A, are the high levels above 2 V and the low levels below 0.8 V? How often are these levels changing?

Comment: Also, do you have a common ground between this circuit and the NI-DAQ board? Is there a connection between the ground of this board and one of the ground pins of the NI-DAQ inputs?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, the ground is common. The voltages on the input pins are above 2V and below 0.8V for high and low respectively. However, the outputs measure a mess.

Comment: If the ADC is providing valid logic levels, there's no reason to think the '5402A wouldn't be able to do the level translation. Note `Voh` is not promised to be any higher than 3.85 V.  When there's a lot of bits transitioning at the same time, does the voltage at the power pin stay fixed (no more than a few mV change from whatever it normally is)?

Comment: @ThePhoton You are right (see the update). When I measure the signal on the input and the output of the '5402A without it being connected to the NI connector blocks, the signal is pretty reasonable, however, after connecting the blocks, the integrity of the output signal decreases. In some places _LOW levels_ right after falling edges seem to be over 0.8V, though maybe it's just a bad probe measurement? Regarding the voltage at the power pin, according the the measurement it fluctuates +-100mV (but it is bypassed!? see schematic).

Comment: This still looks like a ground disconnect or maybe a ground loop problem. Can you make a block diagram showing how ground is connected between the ADC board, the PC with NI board, and any power supplies in the system? Also indicate where you connected the scope probe ground lead for the measurements. A photo of the system would also help us check for any construction issues.

Comment: @ThePhoton I will provide pictures when I get a camera. Now, check this out: I have two wires (one signal, second ground). I housed these wires in the shield which is connected to the PCB ground and NI connectors ground. When I scope the signal at the NI connector, it almost looks like someone's ECG, and not even close to a 50% dutycycle clock. However, disconnecting the wire from the NI block makes the reading correct.

Comment: If you probe the NI input connector with the wire disconnected, do you still see noise?

Comment: @ThePhoton Probing at the NI input reads no noise.

Comment: @ThePhoton I added setup picture.

Comment: Notice the NI box has a ground symbol near some of the bnc connectors, probably indicating the outer shell is connected internally to ground. But it doesn't have this symbol by the connectors you are using. Are you sure you have a ground connection between your board and the NI box?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes. They  are connected.

Comment: How are the green board and the BNC-2110 box connected to each other? Could you have a ground loop there?

Comment: @ThePhoton They are connected to the PCB board and to the PCI, but I did not interconnect them directly. You were right: there is some ground related interference. I once managed to get rid of the problem, but I still can not catch where exactly it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the information from the scope traces, there's still a few things this could be:

- Ground disconnect: Make sure the ground connection between the ADC board and the DAQ board is well-connected.
- Cross-talk: When one line switches it could induce a signal on anther line. This is particularly likely since it looks like you have many more signal lines than ground/return lines. Two ways cross-talk could be created:

  - Mutual inductance: If you move the connection wires around relative to each other, does that reduce the problem? If that's it, try to keep all the signal wires as close to the ground wire as possible. The ~50 ohm series resistance you have in each output should mitigate this, but you never know.

    To reduce this problem, keep the victim signal line as close as possible to the ground wire.
  - Return line impedance: If there's substantial resistance in the return wire (due to a dodgy connector, for example, or if the return wire is much longer than the signal wires creating excess inductance) that could cause a ground bounce that allows a switching current in one wire to affect all the other wires.
- Ground loop: This is less likely, but I'll mention it for completeness. If the ADC board has two different ground connections back to the DAQ system (like one direct connection and one through the power supply to the wall to the other power supply) then this loop could pick up interference. Since the "interference" here seems to be synchronous with the data signal, this is pretty unlikely, but maybe your data is synchronous with some external event?

Comment: I shielded all the cables and connected shields to the ground at the board and at the connector boxes, but the problem remains. Look at the third image from the top (blue signal). This is what I read on one of the pis of '5402 when the connector box is connected. Right after the rising/falling edge, the signal drops/rises respectively. The drop is fine, since it is still higher than the minimum "high" voltage. However, the sudden rise after the falling edge looks like is over 1.5V, whereas should be less than 0.8V to be considered zero. Any other suggestions?